# 389-ds dirsrv-admin will not start after enabling single master replication

Tags: 389-ds

On the supplier server I went ahead and enabled replication. Restarted `dirsrv` and then was receiving `nss shutdown failed error -8038`; so I attempted to restart `dirsrv-admin` and now it fails with the following error:

```
[Mon Jan 06 18:13:55 2014] [crit] host_ip_init(): PSET failure: Failed to create PSET handle (pset error = )
Configuration Failed
```

I enabled debugging of the logs and the full error is below:

```
[Mon Jan 06 18:13:55 2014] [debug] mod_admserv/mod_admserv.c(2106): host_ip_init(): secure connection not enabled, skipping sslinit
[Mon Jan 06 18:13:55 2014] [crit] host_ip_init(): PSET failure: Failed to create PSET handle (pset error = )
Configuration Failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed error by changing ownership in `/etc/dirsrv/<instance>` and `/etc/dirsrv/admin-serv` to the configured user.